# create nested json using python defaultdict

Tags: python

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list)
a['Fruits'].append('Mango')
a['Fruits'].append('Durian')
a['Price'].append(10)

>>> a
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Fruits': ['Mango', 'Durian'], 'Price': [10]})
```

I want to make items in the list as key and add values. Ex:

```
{'Fruits': ['Mango' : ['Thailand', 'China'], 'Durian' : ['Malaysia','Singapore']], 'Price': [10]}
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Your example output isn't a valid Python data structure.

Comment: sorry about the typo.. yes, you are right. Actual output should be  {'Fruits': [{'Mango': ['Thailand', 'China'], 'Durian': ['Malaysia', 'Singapore']})], 'Price': [10]})

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly. Have you made any attempt you could show to implement this? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output is not a in a valid Python format, anyway is possible to understand what you're looking for.
One of the many ways to build this data structure (the most similar to your approach) is the following one:

```
a = defaultdict(list)
b = defaultdict(list)
b['Mango'].append('Thailand')
b['Mango'].append('China')
b['Durian'].append('Malaysia')
b['Durian'].append('Singapore')
a['Fruits'].append(b)
a['Price'].append(10)
```

And this is the confrontation of your desired (invalid) output and actual output:

> Desired Output:

```
{'Fruits': ['Mango' : ['Thailand', 'China'], 'Durian' : ['Malaysia','Singapore']], 'Price': [10]}
```

> Actual Output :

```
{'Fruits': [{'Mango': ['Thailand', 'China'], 'Durian': ['Malaysia', 'Singapore']})], 'Price': [10]})
```

---

Note that, as it is, is not the most pythonic solution nor really clean code, but I suppose you're initializing a defaultdict with lists for a specific reason (bigger code, following a course...?)

Let's say we have a store that sell fruits, and you want to be able to access, for each fruit, the possible origin and the price.

We can start building a small dictionary for each fruit:

```
mango = {
    "origin": ["Thailand", "China"],
    "price": 10
}
durian = {
    "origin": ["Malaysia", "Singapore"],
    "price": 42
}
print(mango['origin']) # OUTPUT: ['Thailand', 'China']
print(durian['price']) # OUTPUT: 42
```

As you can see, we're now able to access different information for each fruit. Now we want to put them together in a single dictionary:

```
store = {}
store['Mango'] = mango
store['Durian'] = durian

print(store['Mango']) # OUTPUT: {'origin': ['Thailand', 'China'], 'price': 10}
print(store['Durian']['origin']) # OUTPUT: ['Malaysia', 'Singapore']
```

And now you can access the whole fruit dict or a specific information inside.

So when the `defaultdict` comes into play?
Assume that you try to access some information about Papaya, a fruit that you didn't insert yet:

```
print(store['Papaya']['price'])
```

it raises the error:

> KeyError: 'Papaya'

It raises an error: `Papaya` is not a key of our `store` dict. But you don't want to have an error raised; it would be better if, when a `key` doesn't exists in our dict, a default value is returned.
That's when `defaultdict` comes into play. As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), *[it] provides a default value for the given key*.

So we want a general `fruit` dictionary, that returns `Value not inserted yet` if the key is not present:

```
my_fruit = defaultdict(lambda: "Value not inserted yet")
```

And the `store` dictionary must return a copy of the `my_fruit` dictionary if the key is not present:

```
my_store = defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(my_fruit))
```

resulting in the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import copy

my_fruit = defaultdict(lambda: "Value not inserted yet")
my_store = defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(my_fruit))

my_store["Mango"]["origin"] = ["Thailand", "China"]
my_store["Mango"]["price"] = 10

my_store["Durian"]["origin"] = ["Malaysia", "Singapore"]
my_store["Durian"]["price"] = 42


print(my_store["Mango"]["price"]) # OUTPUT: 10
print(my_store["Durian"]["origin"]) # OUTPUT: ['Malaysia', 'Singapore']
print(my_store["Mango"]["color"]) # OUTPUT: Value not inserted yet
print(my_store["Papaya"]["price"]) # OUTPUT: Value not inserted yet
```

As you can see, the dictionary works exactly like before, but when we insert an invalid `key` in the `store` dict, we receive back a copy of `my_fruit` dict, and when we insert an invalid `key` for `my_fruit` dict, we print out `Value not inserted yet`.

---

<sub><sup>**NOTE:** you can see the usage of [Lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). These may be some advanced concept, and you may want to do some research/open new questions</sup></sub>

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked.. There is no specific reason for using defaultdict(list). Can you recommend more python solution ?

Comment: @Sun ofc, I'll update my question in some moments. In the example I'll assume you have a store which sell fruits, and for each you have 3 information: the name, a list of location where it can be from and the price